# How to filter unwanted attributes from Twitter timeline using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

The below code gives me all information about each status message.

I would like only the text message and the corresponding name of the person.

How do I filter out the attributes that I do not require?

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(3):
    print(json.dumps(status._json, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline) relative to the home_timeline, you can see the full structure that api returns.

Since api returns a list of dictionaries, you can easily filter each tweet in this way

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(3):
    print(tweet.text)
    print(tweet.user.name)
```